# php password verify returns true to previous session_id() plus random character

Tags: php, password-hash

does anyone tried this on php?

i use password hash like this

```
$superValue = "somerandomcharacter".session_id();
$cookie_value = password_hash($superValue, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$timeInMins = 1 * 60;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + 2400, "/");
```

now the cookie is set successfully!! which has value something like this
$2y$10$PoIb9m9LSwkWkZ15snfr5evG3ZWnZKb1ZHH18DiySNnbBJPuIoP82

when i close the browser the session_id() is destroyed but the cookie stays on (has duration of 2400 seconds) cookie value is "somerandomcharacter" plus the previous sessionid that was destroyed.,

but the funny thing is when i passwordverify the "somerandomcharacter"+sessionid() vs the new "somerandomcharacter"+sessionid()

its always returning correct

i did console.log and found out that my password verify compares this 2 string
$2y$10$PoIb9m9LSwkWkZ15snfr5evG3ZWnZKb1ZHH18DiySNnbBJPuIoP82  <---prev hashed
$2y$10$22zDyP5/AJs3unjBHRineu6Klg/rc39E5xh1k5KAZfw.A3SEwE2Ra  <--new hashed to be compared
it returns 1 instead of blank/0

anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Are you decrypting again before comparing the hashed values? Because if you are, in that case it will return equal.

Comment: Ummm. [comparing those two hashes using `password_verify()` returns false](https://3v4l.org/28Zv5) exactly as it should; password_verify() compares a plaintext password value with a hashed value